# Terracotta - Cannot cast to com.tc.object.bytecode.TransparentAccess

Tags: spring, configuration, terracotta

I have a rather large spring application, and all I'm trying to share is a single Map (using util.ConcurrentMap as implementation).

To do this, I created a bean in my appContext, and I tried to use the following tc-config line:

*/applicationContext.xml

Must I do something else to enable this to work? MyClass is a rather simple domain object that contains only primitives, two constructors, and accessors/mutators.

Must I do something else to get this working? I'm using Terracotta 3.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a tc-config.xml config file as described in http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/orgsite/Spring+Integration.